# How can I install Perl module manually (root) and have non-root users see it

Tags: perl

since I found one answer here (thanks), I figured I'd post a question that I am still working on.

For us it's not an option to use CPAN, so I've installed the needed modules manually.  I log in as myself (non-root) and do the following:

```
cd work-dir
tar -xvf module.tar.gz
cd module
perl Makefile.pl   (except for one below)
make
make test
sudo su -
make install
```

The only exception is for XML::expat (sorry I don't have full name handy). But there's no Makefile.pl, so I do `perl .\configure` instead.

This is great if I can be root all the time, but when I drop back to non-root user, I don't see these modules when I do instmodsh and list them out.

Is there a flag I need to use, chmod 755 on some file that gets created in a library, etc.?

Probably something basic, but I'm drawing a blank, what I know I've tried and got nowhere.  So, hoping someone sees this and chimes in, however basic it may be.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: "it's not an option to use CPAN" — Really? http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=693828

Comment: "I've installed the needed modules manually" — How? What commands did you run?

Comment: Could you show us your install process?  Also, if you can't use CPAN (the repository or the tools) because these are privately developed modules or because you don't have a network connection, consider [Stratopan](https://stratopan.com/) or [Pinto](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pinto::Manual).  These will allow you to use the normal CPAN tools for a private module repository.

Comment: You don't have to do this manually. [cpanm](https://github.com/miyagawa/cpanminus) will work with files and can be installed as a single file. `cpanm module.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're doing something very weird in your install process (which you should show us), the most likely explanation is that root and non-root have different `PATH`s and see different perls.  Check with `which perl`.

Also you should ***never build or test as root***.  One bug or overzealous test and the whole machine could be corrupted.  Build and test as a normal user and use `sudo` for the install.  Using `sudo` instead of logging in as root will have the nice side effect of avoiding the often very different root environment, like different `PATH`s.

Comment: OK, sorry, I wasn't as clear - my bad.  I log in as myself (non-root) and do the following.  I shouldn't rush posts....


1) cd to where the module is (gz) and do tar -xvf module
2) cd to unzipped module
3) perl MakeFile.pl (except for one below)
4) make
5) make test
6) sudo su -
7) make install

The only exception is for XML::expat (sorry I don't have full name handy).  But there's no MakeFile.pl, so I do perl .\configure instead

Thanks for the suggestion, I'll check with which perl tomorrow (no access now) and also look at paths. 

Thanks for the quick reply, really appreciate it.  
Chris

Comment: @ChrisRoo You should [edit] your post with that information.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `sudo make install` instead of `sudo su -` and then `make install`?  The `su -` resets the environment and is probably causing you to install the module into a different Perl installation.

For example, `root` may be using `/usr/bin/perl` while non-root users are using `/usr/local/bin/perl`, and they don't share module directories.